# Rotate an image in a Workbook using openpyxl module in python

Tags: python, openpyxl

Is there a way to rotate an image inserted into a Workbook created with `openpyxl` in Python? I can change the `width` and `height` of the image but there is no rotate attribute for the image. I can definitely import the image using `PIL` and rotate it but that snippet code could not be used with the Workbook.

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

img = Image(r'C:\your path\Image.jpg,png...etc')
img.width= 150
img.height = 200
ws.add_image(img, "C4")
wb.save('imagecheck.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please create an MCVE so we can help you better: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Joooeey you can use `[mre]` in comments to get the link quicker :) like this: [mre]